# Replacing Non-ASCII characters with English Equivalents

Tags: php, ascii

I have searched for an answer to this question for a very long time on here and got many different answers that did not seem to work for me. I am querying a database and then validating the data before I write it to an XML file using fwrite(). I have created the following function to replace all Non-ASCII characters with plain English ones (ie. replace É with E):

```
    function replaceASCII($str) { 
    $search = array(
        'À', 'Á', 'Â', 'Ã', 'Ä', 'Å', 'Æ', 'Ā', 'Ą', 'Ă', 'Ç', 'Ć', 'Č', 'Ĉ', 'Ċ', 'Ď', 'Đ', 'È', 'É', 'Ê', 'Ë', 'Ē', 'Ę', 'Ě', 'Ĕ', 'Ė', 'Ĝ', 'Ğ', 'Ġ',
        'Ģ', 'Ĥ', 'Ħ', 'Ì', 'Í', 'Î', 'Ï', 'Ī', 'Ĩ', 'Ĭ', 'Į', 'İ', 'Ĳ', 'Ĵ', 'Ķ', 'Ľ', 'Ĺ', 'Ļ', 'Ŀ', 'Ł', 'Ñ', 'Ń', 'Ň', 'Ņ', 'Ŋ', 'Ò', 'Ó', 'Ô', 'Õ',
        'Ö', 'Ø', 'Ō', 'Ő', 'Ŏ', 'Œ', 'Ŕ', 'Ř', 'Ŗ', 'Ś', 'Ş', 'Ŝ', 'Ș', 'Š', 'Ť', 'Ţ', 'Ŧ', 'Ț', 'Ù', 'Ú', 'Û', 'Ü', 'Ū', 'Ů', 'Ű', 'Ŭ', 'Ũ', 'Ų', 'Ŵ',
        'Ŷ', 'Ÿ', 'Ý', 'Ź', 'Ż', 'Ž', 'à', 'á', 'â', 'ã', 'ä', 'ā', 'ą', 'ă', 'å', 'æ', 'ç', 'ć', 'č', 'ĉ', 'ċ', 'ď', 'đ', 'è', 'é', 'ê', 'ë', 'ē', 'ę',
        'ě', 'ĕ', 'ė', 'ƒ', 'ĝ', 'ğ', 'ġ', 'ģ', 'ĥ', 'ħ', 'ì', 'í', 'î', 'ï', 'ī', 'ĩ', 'ĭ', 'į', 'ı', 'ĳ', 'ĵ', 'ķ', 'ĸ', 'ł', 'ľ', 'ĺ', 'ļ', 'ŀ', 'ñ',
        'ń', 'ň', 'ņ', 'ŉ', 'ŋ', 'ò', 'ó', 'ô', 'õ', 'ö', 'ø', 'ō', 'ő', 'ŏ', 'œ', 'ŕ', 'ř', 'ŗ', 'ś', 'š', 'ş', 'ť', 'ţ', 'ù', 'ú', 'û', 'ü', 'ū', 'ů',
        'ű', 'ŭ', 'ũ', 'ų', 'ŵ', 'ÿ', 'ý', 'ŷ', 'ż', 'ź', 'ž', 'ß', 'ſ', 'Α', 'Ά', 'Ἀ', 'Ἁ', 'Ἂ', 'Ἃ', 'Ἄ', 'Ἅ', 'Ἆ', 'Ἇ', 'ᾈ', 'ᾉ', 'ᾊ', 'ᾋ', 'ᾌ',
        'ᾍ', 'ᾎ', 'ᾏ', 'Ᾰ', 'Ᾱ', 'Ὰ', 'Ά', 'ᾼ', 'Β', 'Γ', 'Δ', 'Ε', 'Έ', 'Ἐ', 'Ἑ', 'Ἒ', 'Ἓ', 'Ἔ', 'Ἕ', 'Έ', 'Ὲ', 'Ζ', 'Η', 'Ή', 'Ἠ', 'Ἡ', 'Ἢ',
        'Ἣ', 'Ἤ', 'Ἥ', 'Ἦ', 'Ἧ', 'ᾘ', 'ᾙ', 'ᾚ', 'ᾛ', 'ᾜ', 'ᾝ', 'ᾞ', 'ᾟ', 'Ὴ', 'Ή', 'ῌ', 'Θ', 'Ι', 'Ί', 'Ϊ', 'Ἰ', 'Ἱ', 'Ἲ', 'Ἳ', 'Ἴ', 'Ἵ', 'Ἶ',
        'Ἷ', 'Ῐ', 'Ῑ', 'Ὶ', 'Ί', 'Κ', 'Λ', 'Μ', 'Ν', 'Ξ', 'Ο', 'Ό', 'Ὀ', 'Ὁ', 'Ὂ', 'Ὃ', 'Ὄ', 'Ὅ', 'Ὸ', 'Ό', 'Π', 'Ρ', 'Ῥ', 'Σ', 'Τ', 'Υ', 'Ύ', 'Ϋ',
        'Ὑ', 'Ὓ', 'Ὕ', 'Ὗ', 'Ῠ', 'Ῡ', 'Ὺ', 'Ύ', 'Φ', 'Χ', 'Ψ', 'Ω', 'Ώ', 'Ὠ', 'Ὡ', 'Ὢ', 'Ὣ', 'Ὤ', 'Ὥ', 'Ὦ', 'Ὧ', 'ᾨ', 'ᾩ', 'ᾪ', 'ᾫ', 'ᾬ', 'ᾭ',
        'ᾮ', 'ᾯ', 'Ὼ', 'Ώ', 'ῼ', 'α', 'ά', 'ἀ', 'ἁ', 'ἂ', 'ἃ', 'ἄ', 'ἅ', 'ἆ', 'ἇ', 'ᾀ', 'ᾁ', 'ᾂ', 'ᾃ', 'ᾄ', 'ᾅ', 'ᾆ', 'ᾇ', 'ὰ', 'ά', 'ᾰ', 'ᾱ', 'ᾲ',
        'ᾳ', 'ᾴ', 'ᾶ', 'ᾷ', 'β', 'γ', 'δ', 'ε', 'έ', 'ἐ', 'ἑ', 'ἒ', 'ἓ', 'ἔ', 'ἕ', 'ὲ', 'έ', 'ζ', 'η', 'ή', 'ἠ', 'ἡ', 'ἢ', 'ἣ', 'ἤ', 'ἥ', 'ἦ', 'ἧ', 'ᾐ',
        'ᾑ', 'ᾒ', 'ᾓ', 'ᾔ', 'ᾕ', 'ᾖ', 'ᾗ', 'ὴ', 'ή', 'ῂ', 'ῃ', 'ῄ', 'ῆ', 'ῇ', 'θ', 'ι', 'ί', 'ϊ', 'ΐ', 'ἰ', 'ἱ', 'ἲ', 'ἳ', 'ἴ', 'ἵ', 'ἶ', 'ἷ', 'ὶ', 'ί', 'ῐ',
        'ῑ', 'ῒ', 'ΐ', 'ῖ', 'ῗ', 'κ', 'λ', 'μ', 'ν', 'ξ', 'ο', 'ό', 'ὀ', 'ὁ', 'ὂ', 'ὃ', 'ὄ', 'ὅ', 'ὸ', 'ό', 'π', 'ρ', 'ῤ', 'ῥ', 'σ', 'ς', 'τ', 'υ', 'ύ',
        'ϋ', 'ΰ', 'ὐ', 'ὑ', 'ὒ', 'ὓ', 'ὔ', 'ὕ', 'ὖ', 'ὗ', 'ὺ', 'ύ', 'ῠ', 'ῡ', 'ῢ', 'ΰ', 'ῦ', 'ῧ', 'φ', 'χ', 'ψ', 'ω', 'ώ', 'ὠ', 'ὡ', 'ὢ', 'ὣ', 'ὤ',
        'ὥ', 'ὦ', 'ὧ', 'ᾠ', 'ᾡ', 'ᾢ', 'ᾣ', 'ᾤ', 'ᾥ', 'ᾦ', 'ᾧ', 'ὼ', 'ώ', 'ῲ', 'ῳ', 'ῴ', 'ῶ', 'ῷ', '¨', '΅', '᾿', '῾', '῍', '῝', '῎', '῞', '῏', '῟',
        '῀', '῁', '΄', '΅', '`', '῭', 'ͺ', '᾽', 'А', 'Б', 'В', 'Г', 'Д', 'Е', 'Ё', 'Ж', 'З', 'И', 'Й', 'К', 'Л', 'М', 'Н', 'О', 'П', 'Р', 'С', 'Т', 'У', 'Ф',
        'Х', 'Ц', 'Ч', 'Ш', 'Щ', 'Ы', 'Э', 'Ю', 'Я', 'а', 'б', 'в', 'г', 'д', 'е', 'ё', 'ж', 'з', 'и', 'й', 'к', 'л', 'м', 'н', 'о', 'п', 'р', 'с', 'т',
        'у', 'ф', 'х', 'ц', 'ч', 'ш', 'щ', 'ы', 'э', 'ю', 'я', 'Ъ', 'ъ', 'Ь', 'ь', 'ð', 'Ð', 'þ', 'Þ',
        '\'','&','<','>','\'','\"');


    $replace = array(
        'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'ae', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'g', 'g',
        'g', 'g', 'h', 'h', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'ij', 'j', 'k', 'k', 'k', 'k', 'k', 'l', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'o', 'o',
        'o', 'o', 'oe', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'oe', 'r', 'r', 'r', 's', 's', 's', 's', 's', 't', 't', 't', 't', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'ue', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u',
        'u', 'u', 'w', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'z', 'z', 'z', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'ae', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'ae', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'e',
        'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'h', 'h', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'ij', 'j', 'k', 'k', 'l',
        'l', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'oe', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'oe', 'r', 'r', 'r', 's', 's', 's', 't', 't',
        'u', 'u', 'u', 'ue', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'w', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'z', 'z', 'z', 'ss', 'ss', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a',
        'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'g', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'z', 'i',
        'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'th', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i',
        'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'ks', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'p', 'r', 'r', 's', 't',
        'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'f', 'x', 'ps', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o',
        'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a',
        'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'g', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'z', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i',
        'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'th', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i',
        'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'ks', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'p', 'r', 'r', 'r', 's',
        's', 't', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'f', 'x', 'ps', 'o', 'o', 'o',
        'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
        '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'a', 'b', 'v', 'g', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'zh', 'z', 'i', 'i', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'f',
        'kh', 'ts', 'ch', 'sh', 'shch', 'y', 'e', 'yu', 'ya', 'a', 'b', 'v', 'g', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'zh', 'z', 'i', 'i', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p',
        'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'f', 'kh', 'ts', 'ch', 'sh', 'shch', 'y', 'e', 'yu', 'ya', '', '', '', '', 'd', 'd', 'th', 'th',
        '','&amp;','&lt;','&gt;','&apos;','&quot;');

    $str = str_replace( $search, $replace, $str );
    return $str;
}
```

I then use this function on each separate field I pull from the database within the oci_fetch_array method. Example:

```
function validate_data($array){
while($row=oci_fetch_array($array, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)){
    {
    //VALIDATE ALL NON ASCII CHARACTERS 
    if(isset($row["UNIQUE ID"])){
        $uniqueID=$row["UNIQUE ID"];
        $uniqueID=replaceASCII($uniqueID);
    }
    if(isset($row["LAST NAME"])){
    $lastname=$row["LAST NAME"];
    $lastname=replaceASCII($lastname);
    }
```

And then I use these new variables while writing the file like this:

```
fwrite($requestfile,'<contact contactID="'.$uniqueID.'" action="AddOrModify">');
```

For some reason, only some parts of the code are being changed, but other letters with accents are remaining. For example all instances of "&" are successfully being changed to "&", but all of the "í"'s are remaining within the XML file. Any ideas?

EDIT

I just tried using the same function within a test file and it worked perfectly fine with this code:

```
    <?php
function replaceASCII($str) { 
    $search = array(
        'À', 'Á', 'Â', 'Ã', 'Ä', 'Å', 'Æ', 'Ā', 'Ą', 'Ă', 'Ç', 'Ć', 'Č', 'Ĉ', 'Ċ', 'Ď', 'Đ', 'È', 'É', 'Ê', 'Ë', 'Ē', 'Ę', 'Ě', 'Ĕ', 'Ė', 'Ĝ', 'Ğ', 'Ġ',
        'Ģ', 'Ĥ', 'Ħ', 'Ì', 'Í', 'Î', 'Ï', 'Ī', 'Ĩ', 'Ĭ', 'Į', 'İ', 'Ĳ', 'Ĵ', 'Ķ', 'Ľ', 'Ĺ', 'Ļ', 'Ŀ', 'Ł', 'Ñ', 'Ń', 'Ň', 'Ņ', 'Ŋ', 'Ò', 'Ó', 'Ô', 'Õ',
        'Ö', 'Ø', 'Ō', 'Ő', 'Ŏ', 'Œ', 'Ŕ', 'Ř', 'Ŗ', 'Ś', 'Ş', 'Ŝ', 'Ș', 'Š', 'Ť', 'Ţ', 'Ŧ', 'Ț', 'Ù', 'Ú', 'Û', 'Ü', 'Ū', 'Ů', 'Ű', 'Ŭ', 'Ũ', 'Ų', 'Ŵ',
        'Ŷ', 'Ÿ', 'Ý', 'Ź', 'Ż', 'Ž', 'à', 'á', 'â', 'ã', 'ä', 'ā', 'ą', 'ă', 'å', 'æ', 'ç', 'ć', 'č', 'ĉ', 'ċ', 'ď', 'đ', 'è', 'é', 'ê', 'ë', 'ē', 'ę',
        'ě', 'ĕ', 'ė', 'ƒ', 'ĝ', 'ğ', 'ġ', 'ģ', 'ĥ', 'ħ', 'ì', 'í', 'î', 'ï', 'ī', 'ĩ', 'ĭ', 'į', 'ı', 'ĳ', 'ĵ', 'ķ', 'ĸ', 'ł', 'ľ', 'ĺ', 'ļ', 'ŀ', 'ñ',
        'ń', 'ň', 'ņ', 'ŉ', 'ŋ', 'ò', 'ó', 'ô', 'õ', 'ö', 'ø', 'ō', 'ő', 'ŏ', 'œ', 'ŕ', 'ř', 'ŗ', 'ś', 'š', 'ş', 'ť', 'ţ', 'ù', 'ú', 'û', 'ü', 'ū', 'ů',
        'ű', 'ŭ', 'ũ', 'ų', 'ŵ', 'ÿ', 'ý', 'ŷ', 'ż', 'ź', 'ž', 'ß', 'ſ', 'Α', 'Ά', 'Ἀ', 'Ἁ', 'Ἂ', 'Ἃ', 'Ἄ', 'Ἅ', 'Ἆ', 'Ἇ', 'ᾈ', 'ᾉ', 'ᾊ', 'ᾋ', 'ᾌ',
        'ᾍ', 'ᾎ', 'ᾏ', 'Ᾰ', 'Ᾱ', 'Ὰ', 'Ά', 'ᾼ', 'Β', 'Γ', 'Δ', 'Ε', 'Έ', 'Ἐ', 'Ἑ', 'Ἒ', 'Ἓ', 'Ἔ', 'Ἕ', 'Έ', 'Ὲ', 'Ζ', 'Η', 'Ή', 'Ἠ', 'Ἡ', 'Ἢ',
        'Ἣ', 'Ἤ', 'Ἥ', 'Ἦ', 'Ἧ', 'ᾘ', 'ᾙ', 'ᾚ', 'ᾛ', 'ᾜ', 'ᾝ', 'ᾞ', 'ᾟ', 'Ὴ', 'Ή', 'ῌ', 'Θ', 'Ι', 'Ί', 'Ϊ', 'Ἰ', 'Ἱ', 'Ἲ', 'Ἳ', 'Ἴ', 'Ἵ', 'Ἶ',
        'Ἷ', 'Ῐ', 'Ῑ', 'Ὶ', 'Ί', 'Κ', 'Λ', 'Μ', 'Ν', 'Ξ', 'Ο', 'Ό', 'Ὀ', 'Ὁ', 'Ὂ', 'Ὃ', 'Ὄ', 'Ὅ', 'Ὸ', 'Ό', 'Π', 'Ρ', 'Ῥ', 'Σ', 'Τ', 'Υ', 'Ύ', 'Ϋ',
        'Ὑ', 'Ὓ', 'Ὕ', 'Ὗ', 'Ῠ', 'Ῡ', 'Ὺ', 'Ύ', 'Φ', 'Χ', 'Ψ', 'Ω', 'Ώ', 'Ὠ', 'Ὡ', 'Ὢ', 'Ὣ', 'Ὤ', 'Ὥ', 'Ὦ', 'Ὧ', 'ᾨ', 'ᾩ', 'ᾪ', 'ᾫ', 'ᾬ', 'ᾭ',
        'ᾮ', 'ᾯ', 'Ὼ', 'Ώ', 'ῼ', 'α', 'ά', 'ἀ', 'ἁ', 'ἂ', 'ἃ', 'ἄ', 'ἅ', 'ἆ', 'ἇ', 'ᾀ', 'ᾁ', 'ᾂ', 'ᾃ', 'ᾄ', 'ᾅ', 'ᾆ', 'ᾇ', 'ὰ', 'ά', 'ᾰ', 'ᾱ', 'ᾲ',
        'ᾳ', 'ᾴ', 'ᾶ', 'ᾷ', 'β', 'γ', 'δ', 'ε', 'έ', 'ἐ', 'ἑ', 'ἒ', 'ἓ', 'ἔ', 'ἕ', 'ὲ', 'έ', 'ζ', 'η', 'ή', 'ἠ', 'ἡ', 'ἢ', 'ἣ', 'ἤ', 'ἥ', 'ἦ', 'ἧ', 'ᾐ',
        'ᾑ', 'ᾒ', 'ᾓ', 'ᾔ', 'ᾕ', 'ᾖ', 'ᾗ', 'ὴ', 'ή', 'ῂ', 'ῃ', 'ῄ', 'ῆ', 'ῇ', 'θ', 'ι', 'ί', 'ϊ', 'ΐ', 'ἰ', 'ἱ', 'ἲ', 'ἳ', 'ἴ', 'ἵ', 'ἶ', 'ἷ', 'ὶ', 'ί', 'ῐ',
        'ῑ', 'ῒ', 'ΐ', 'ῖ', 'ῗ', 'κ', 'λ', 'μ', 'ν', 'ξ', 'ο', 'ό', 'ὀ', 'ὁ', 'ὂ', 'ὃ', 'ὄ', 'ὅ', 'ὸ', 'ό', 'π', 'ρ', 'ῤ', 'ῥ', 'σ', 'ς', 'τ', 'υ', 'ύ',
        'ϋ', 'ΰ', 'ὐ', 'ὑ', 'ὒ', 'ὓ', 'ὔ', 'ὕ', 'ὖ', 'ὗ', 'ὺ', 'ύ', 'ῠ', 'ῡ', 'ῢ', 'ΰ', 'ῦ', 'ῧ', 'φ', 'χ', 'ψ', 'ω', 'ώ', 'ὠ', 'ὡ', 'ὢ', 'ὣ', 'ὤ',
        'ὥ', 'ὦ', 'ὧ', 'ᾠ', 'ᾡ', 'ᾢ', 'ᾣ', 'ᾤ', 'ᾥ', 'ᾦ', 'ᾧ', 'ὼ', 'ώ', 'ῲ', 'ῳ', 'ῴ', 'ῶ', 'ῷ', '¨', '΅', '᾿', '῾', '῍', '῝', '῎', '῞', '῏', '῟',
        '῀', '῁', '΄', '΅', '`', '῭', 'ͺ', '᾽', 'А', 'Б', 'В', 'Г', 'Д', 'Е', 'Ё', 'Ж', 'З', 'И', 'Й', 'К', 'Л', 'М', 'Н', 'О', 'П', 'Р', 'С', 'Т', 'У', 'Ф',
        'Х', 'Ц', 'Ч', 'Ш', 'Щ', 'Ы', 'Э', 'Ю', 'Я', 'а', 'б', 'в', 'г', 'д', 'е', 'ё', 'ж', 'з', 'и', 'й', 'к', 'л', 'м', 'н', 'о', 'п', 'р', 'с', 'т',
        'у', 'ф', 'х', 'ц', 'ч', 'ш', 'щ', 'ы', 'э', 'ю', 'я', 'Ъ', 'ъ', 'Ь', 'ь', 'ð', 'Ð', 'þ', 'Þ',
        '\'','&','<','>','\'','\"');


    $replace = array(
        'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'ae', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'g', 'g',
        'g', 'g', 'h', 'h', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'ij', 'j', 'k', 'k', 'k', 'k', 'k', 'l', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'o', 'o',
        'o', 'o', 'oe', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'oe', 'r', 'r', 'r', 's', 's', 's', 's', 's', 't', 't', 't', 't', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'ue', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u',
        'u', 'u', 'w', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'z', 'z', 'z', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'ae', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'ae', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'e',
        'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'h', 'h', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'ij', 'j', 'k', 'k', 'l',
        'l', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'oe', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'oe', 'r', 'r', 'r', 's', 's', 's', 't', 't',
        'u', 'u', 'u', 'ue', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'w', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'z', 'z', 'z', 'ss', 'ss', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a',
        'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'g', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'z', 'i',
        'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'th', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i',
        'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'ks', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'p', 'r', 'r', 's', 't',
        'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'f', 'x', 'ps', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o',
        'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a',
        'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'g', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'z', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i',
        'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'th', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i',
        'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'ks', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'p', 'r', 'r', 'r', 's',
        's', 't', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'f', 'x', 'ps', 'o', 'o', 'o',
        'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
        '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'a', 'b', 'v', 'g', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'zh', 'z', 'i', 'i', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'f',
        'kh', 'ts', 'ch', 'sh', 'shch', 'y', 'e', 'yu', 'ya', 'a', 'b', 'v', 'g', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'zh', 'z', 'i', 'i', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p',
        'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'f', 'kh', 'ts', 'ch', 'sh', 'shch', 'y', 'e', 'yu', 'ya', '', '', '', '', 'd', 'd', 'th', 'th',
        '','&amp;','&lt;','&gt;','&apos;','&quot;');

    $str = str_replace( $search, $replace, $str );
    return $str;
}

$string="François &<> Cédric";
echo $string . "<br>";
$string=replaceASCII($string);
echo $string;
$file=fopen('C:\Users\ps526695\Documents\ContactExports\test\test_request.xml','w');
fwrite($file,$string);
//echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $string);
?>
```

Now I'm not sure why it isnt working for the production file?

Comment: I'd also like to add that I have tried using the inconv method with similar issues.

Comment: It might be due to the use of combining characters. For instance, your `í` might be a single character or an `i` with a combining character `'`. If you have one version in your array and another one in the XML file, the replace won't work. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character

Comment: Hmm, didnt think about that. Any idea how to handle those cases?

Comment: I edited your question in order to avoid `&amp;` show up as `&` - `For example all instances of "&" are successfully being changed to "&",` in your question. People will wonder about that. You need to use backticks `\`` around `&amp;` in order to show up as `&amp;`. But, you overwrote it.

Comment: @ITProblems 'Normalize' them:  http://php.net/manual/en/class.normalizer.php

Comment: I'm not sure what your aim is. In modern Danish, "å" replaces "aa" (except in place names the old spelling is used, as in Aalborg). Transliteration requires knowing the source language as well as the script.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is due to the use of [combining characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character). For instance, your `í` might be a single character or an `i` with a combining character `'`. If you have one version in your array and another one in the XML file, the replace won't work.

PHP has a class named 'Normalizer' that handles this. The class contains two static methods, one to check whether a string is normalized, and another to normalize a string to one of the various normalized forms define by the Unicode Consortium.

I've not used this class myself, but it looks like it works simply like this:

```
$str = Normalizer::normalize($str);
```

If is still doesn't work, make sure the characters in your array are also normalized. You should be able to use `Normalizer::isNormalized()` for that.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/class.normalizer.php